Having trouble mocking response from Microsoft Graph Api 5.54.0
I have a service that is a wrapper around Microsoft Graph that I am trying to unit test.  I have my mocking working, but my mocked response always returns as null.
Here is the setup for my mocks:
 protected GraphServiceClient _graphClient;
 protected Mock<HttpMessageHandler> _messageHandlerMock;
 protected HttpClient _httpClientMock;
 protected Mock<TokenCredential> _tokenCredentialMock;

 protected const string _groupsApiUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups";
 protected const string _invitationsApiUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations";

 [SetUp]
 public virtual void BeforeEachTest()
 {

     _httpClientFactoryMock = new Mock<IHttpClientFactory>();
     _messageHandlerMock = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
     _tokenCredentialMock = new Mock<TokenCredential>();

     _httpClientMock = new HttpClient(_messageHandlerMock.Object);

     _httpClientFactoryMock.Setup(_ => _.CreateClient(It.IsAny<string>()))
         .Returns(_httpClientMock);

     _tokenCredentialMock.Setup(_ => _.GetTokenAsync(It.IsAny<TokenRequestContext>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
         .ReturnsAsync(new AccessToken(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1)));

     _graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(_httpClientMock, _tokenCredentialMock.Object);

 }

And what I use to configure Moq to intercept http requests
protected string? ConfigureInvitationsMock()
{
    var invitationUrl = $"https://test.com/invitation/{Guid.NewGuid()}";

    var invitation = new Invitation()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        InviteRedeemUrl = invitationUrl
    };

    _messageHandlerMock.Protected()
        .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync",
            ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(x => x.Method == HttpMethod.Post
                                               && x.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith(_invitationsApiUrl)),
            ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
        .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Content = new ByteArrayContent(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonSerializer.Serialize(invitation)))
        });

    return invitationUrl;
}

And my simple test that makes sure my method returns the invitation url when it's not null from Graph
[Test]
public async Task GetInvitationUriAsync_ReturnsInvitationUrl()
{
    var expected = ConfigureInvitationsMock();

    var recipient = new InvitationRecipientDto()
    {
        DisplayName = _displayName,
        EmailAddress = _email,
        RedirectAfterRegistration = _redirectUri,
        EntraTenantId = _entraTenantId
    };

    var result = await _target.GetInvitationUriAsync(recipient);

    result.ShouldNotBeNull();
    result.AbsoluteUri.ShouldBe(expected);
}

result.ShouldNotBeNull(); is always failing because the Uri thati s returned is always null.
The response from the Microsoft Graph Client is always null in my unit tests, even though you can clearly see in the mock I am returning a serialized Invitation
I'm am sure my mock is correctly defined because of I comment it out, Microsoft Graph errors saying there was no response.  Alsom f I change the Status Code on the response to InternalServerError, Graph throws an exception about getting an error from the service.  So the problem lies exclusively in the format of the response and how graph is just returning null for some reason.

There's a lot of code there, and as far as I can tell, not even all of it. For instance, your System Under Test calls BuildRequest, but we can't see that method. How can we help you in that case? Please edit the question so that it presents a minimal reproducible example. Please note the minimal part. You probably don't need to add more code to the post, but rather remove code so that the example is self-contained and still reproduces the problem.

I removed the irrelevant code.  I thought it would be helpful to see the code under test.  The issue at hand is not in my code, it has to do with mocking the GraphServiceClient using Moq so that it returns content instead of null.

Are you sure you really want to spend all that energy mocking the internals of the graph http implementation instead of wrapping the client in a simple humble object that you can create a stub for?

Your code is still not self contained
